# I am trying to run a test on multiple Browsers using MSTest and Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, visual-studio-2015, mstest, ui-testing

I am simultaneously teaching myself Selenium 3.0 and Programming to learn how to Automate my tests (previously a manual tester with no IT background, fell into testing via UAT).

I have successfully written a handful of tests all of which work :). I can define which browser to run the test set on, but cant run the test set on multiple browsers as 1 test run. (I have to define the browser in my Test Initialise and comment out the other browsers). When I try to run the test on 2 browsers at once Browser A opens but nothing runs, Browser B then opens and runs the tests.

I have looked through the posts on this site and on google generally but have not found a clear answer to how to get this to work using MSTest and Semenium in C#

My Code
 One of my tests

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Kukd_Consumer_Tests;

namespace Kukd_Consumer_Test
{
   //login from Hompage

    [TestClass]
    public class Login : Consumer_Standard_Functionality
    {


        [TestMethod]
        public void User_Can_Login() 
        {

           LoginPage.LoginAs("Richard.Cariven@Kukd.Com").WithPassword("Test1234").Login();
           Assert.IsTrue(AccountPageAssert.IsAtAccountPage("Hi Richard"), "Failed to login");
        }
    }
}
```

My std Functionality Test Class (Initialise and Cleanup steps)

```
using Kukd_Consumer_Tests;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Kukd_Consumer_Test
{
    public class Consumer_Standard_Functionality
    {
        [TestInitialize]
        public void Init()
        {
            driver.InitializeChrome();
            driver.InitializeFireFox();
            Homepage.GoTo_HomePage();
        }


        [TestCleanup]
        public void Cleanup()
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

My driver class

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using System;

namespace Kukd_Consumer_Tests
{
    public class driver
    {
        public static IWebDriver Instance { get; set; }

        public static void InitializeChrome()
        {
            Instance = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Drivers\Chrome");
            Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        }

        public static void InitializeFireFox()
        {
            Instance = new FirefoxDriver();
            Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

public static void Quit()
        {
            Instance.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

My LoginPage class

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Kukd_Consumer_Tests
{
    public class LoginPage
    {


        public static LoginCommand LoginAs(string userName)
        {
            return new LoginCommand(userName);
        }

        public class LoginCommand
        {            
            private readonly string userName;
            private string password;

            public LoginCommand(string userName)
            {

                this.userName = userName;

            }

            public LoginCommand WithPassword(string password)
            {
                this.password = password;
                return this;
            }

            public void Login()
            {
                var accountButton = driver.Instance.FindElement(By.LinkText("My Account"));
                accountButton.Click();

                var loginInput = driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("login-email"));
                loginInput.SendKeys(userName);

                var passwordInput = driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("login-password"));
                passwordInput.SendKeys(password);

                var loginButton = driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("loginBtn"));
                loginButton.Click();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the above Chrome opens a blank window and does nothing more. Firefox opens the homepage, then runs the test as expected and closes the window when done.

Comment: Without getting too specific, you could use a data driven approach. When you run DD test, it'll run the method for each row in a data source. In this case, your data source could just be the browsers you want to use. Alternatively, if you are using a CI tool like Jenkins, you could set some environment variables, and have logic to choose the driver based on those variables, and your Jenkins job can trigger the suite per browser.

Comment: Adding to what mrfreester said, you would add a `[DataSource()]` attribute to your `TestMethod` and then you would access the `TestContext.DataRow` where you would simply define a separate row for each browser you want to execute against for TestInitialize. That should give you enough to search on. However, consider a setup where each test run runs against one browser split up on pcs or vms. That's the only way to support execution against multiple versions of the same browser (like IE 9, 10, 11.)

Comment: Thanks for the 2 solutions, after having a look at this I think I am going to switch Frameworks to Nunit or maybe Xunit, Browserstack provides far simpler integration into these frameworks as opposed to MSTest and they look more flexible in there behaviour. Thanks for your support helping me get this far :).